# MCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

Tags: android, java

Начал читать книжку по андроиду и встретил это. Не могли бы вы пояснить смысл данной строки?

```
  mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
```

Мне непонятно все после знака `=`. Ну, кроме `.length`. )

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: Так не совсем понятно, выложи код или страницу из книги.

Comment: `mCurrentIndex + 1` непонятно? о_О

Comment: Это такой классический пример кода для выбора индекса следующего элемента. Если текущий элемент является последним в списке, то следующим будет самый первый (с нулевым индексом).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

`(mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;` - перебор по кругу всех индексов массива.

`%` - остаток от деления

например:

`.length` - длина массива

```
mQuestionBank = 5
```

начальное значение `mCurrentIndex = 0` затем:

```
(0+1)%5 = 1;
(1+1)%5 = 2;
(2+1)%5 = 3;
(3+1)%5 = 4;
(4+1)%5 = 0;
```

и т.д.